# How to remove all files that have been added to a Windows 10 file system from a certain account since a certain time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems

My Windows 10 system has several accounts. I'd like to reset just one of them to its initial state. More accurately, I'd like to delete permanently any and all files that the user may have added to the file system since a certain time.

Alternatively, is it possible to restrict the account so that files can only be added to a specific folder of my choosing, so I may simply delete the folder's content whenever I want to?

To give more context: I'm a teacher and the computer is one on which several students will be administered the same exam. I would like to remove the possibility that one of them will leave a solution to the following students in some path that they have agreed upon in advance.

The account won't have permissions to connect to the Internet, so this is not a concern.

Comment: How is the test accessed or administered? The simplest method is to delete the profile each time and it gets recreated when the person signs in again. This guarantees a clean profile. If you wish the profile to be recreated with shortcuts you can place them in the Default profile folder, as this folder is copied when a new profile folder is created.

Comment: When the tests are administered, where are the results stored? Files on the disk?

Comment: @harrymc Yes. The students are given a programming assignment. They write a program consisting of a single file, using an IDE, and save this file, say, to the desktop. I then copy the file to a flashdrive, and delete it from the computer (and empty the recycle bin). Then the next student gets his/her turn.

Comment: Faronics deep freeze might work

Comment: or perhaps Mandatory User Profile https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/gg241183(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN